# How to remove text formatting when pasting from clipboard on Android

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, copy-paste

Right now I am working on an Android application that requires allowing the user to cut copy and paste onto an `editText` fields. But when I copy a formatted string from other places (i.e. a string that is underlined) and paste it on to the `editText` field, it shows it as a formatted version. How do I remove this?

I have tried to add a `textwatcher` by adding `addTextChangedListener`, and in the after text change I just do `edittext.setText(s.toString()+"")` but this creates an infinite loop. :(

Please help! Thanks in advance.

Edit----
I have made some progress by setting setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback

```
editDestination_.setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {return true;}
        @Override
        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {}
        @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
             menu.removeItem(android.R.id.paste);
             menu.removeItem(android.R.id.selectAll);
             menu.add(0, CUSTOM_PASTE, 0, "Paste").setIcon(R.drawable.paste_ic);
                return true;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
             switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case CUSTOM_PASTE:
                       edittext.setText(readFromClipboard(aContext_));
                    // Finish and close the ActionMode
                    mode.finish();
                    return true;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

This is working pretty well until I realize there are two types of cut/copy/and paste on my phone. One is when the edit text is empty and I long click on the field. This bring up a popup menu. The other one is when there is text in the field, and when I long click, this bring up a cut/copy/and paste bar below my action bar. My code from above is only affecting the bar-below-action bar one. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it.

I set a `onLongClickListener` to catch it before the popup-cut/copy/paste menu shows up.

```
CharSequence actions[] = new CharSequence[] {"paste"};
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setCancelable(true);
builder.setItems(actions, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        edittext.setText(readFromClipboard(aContext_));
    }
});
builder.show();
```

Then if there is a string already present in the `EditText`, I return `false` to allow normal android system below-action-bar-cut/copy/paste function to work.

Answer (score 0):

**PROBLEM :**

The thing you are doing is creating an infinite loop because everytime you call `setText()`, again `afterTextChanged()` gets called (because you are changing the text inside the `EditText`.

**SOLUTION :**

Suppose the `EditText` is `editTextToClearStyle`

```
EditText editTextToClearStyle   = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.youredittextname);

editTextToClearStyle.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
           editTextToClearStyle.setTextAppearance(getApplicationContext(),R.style.normalText);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but this doesn't work :(. I added this as the normalText style   <color name="Black">#000000</color>

<style name="normalText" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.EditText"> 
        <item name="android:textSize">30sp</item> 
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/Black</item> 
        <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
    </style>

Comment: what is the problem you are facing now?